# Error fatal - No such file or directory

Tags: c++11, ubuntu, compiler-errors, x86-64, libcds

I have installed the cds library with command `./build.sh -b 64 -z '-std=c++0x' -l '-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --with-boost /usr/include/boost --amd64-use-128bit` at `build` folder.

After I tried to compile the example `init.cpp` of `src` folder, I typed this in terminal: `g++ init.cpp -o init`, and terminal showed: `fatal error: cds/init.h: No such file or directory`.

What should I do for compilation command in this case?
Thanks.

Comment: Is '-L /usr/ib/x86_64-linux-gnu' just a typo? (You probably meant '-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' )

Comment: Thanks for corrected.

Comment: Did you install `libcds` or did you just build it? Can you verify that `cds/init.h` is somewhere in `/usr/include` directory?

Comment: I can't find `cds` folder. So the command `./build.sh -b 64 -z '-std=c++0x' -l '-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --with-boost /usr/include/boost --amd64-use-128bit` is not for installation? According to this [forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/libcds/discussion/1034512/thread/97cf3473/)

Comment: As the name implies, the script builds it. You still need to install it. Usually done with `make install` if `build.sh` successfully created a `Makefile`.

Comment: I have a `Makefile` in `build` folder, and I tried to run `make install Makefile` in terminal, output>> `make: ***No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.`

Answer (score 0):

For general troubleshooting in cases like this, i would recommend finding where on the system the file got installed (if your build.sh actually installed the file). You would be able to find the missing header file using

```
find / -path '*/cds/init.h' 2>/dev/null
```

Then you need to supply two parameters to g++:

First one gets the compiler to know about the include files from the install directory

-I path_to_folder_one_step_above_cds_folder

Second one gets the linker to know about the librarys location. If the library file  is called libcds.so, you can find it by running

```
find / -name libcds.so 2>/dev/null
```

So for linking, you supply the flag

-L path_to_folder_one_step_above_libcds.so

In your case you might not need the -L flag, since most of your library supposedly is header only.

UPDATE: the build.sh script is printing out important information at the top, starting with "Building with the following options:". The important bits will be "Compile options:" and "Link options:". Those should be enough to solve your specific option.

UPDATE2: build.sh also exports some flags which might include more options. You can print them out directly after running build.sh by running

```
echo LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS
echo CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
echo CXXFLAGS=$CXXFLAGS
```

you are likely to need to pass all these options to g++ when compiling and linking against that library. LDFLAGS are specific to the linker only. Both the other ones are needed for compiling c++ files.